# Implementing Back Pressure on Service - Service REST calls

Tags: asynchronous, reactive-programming

What is the correct pattern for creating back pressure on service to service API calls in reactive systems?

We have a service that reads a message from SQS, does a few REST calls, processes the data and adds the result to the DB. We spiked a reactive implementation of this, but if the downstream requests do not block, the service just keeps pulling messages from SQS which creates more downstream REST calls which eventually the downstream services can't keep up with.

We cannot drop the messages.

Buffering is suggested, but it's preferable to leave messages on the queue rather than pull them into the application and increase the memory footprint.

So we need to control the rate the service pulls the messages from SQS. It seems like we would either need to put a limit on the maximum number of messages we process concurrently or detect slowness in downstream system via response times or 503s and back off message processing until to recovers. The former seems like it prevents scaling and the latter seems like it would need us to block, but reading around suggests that back pressure should be non blocking.

Presumably this is a common challenge. Is there a recommended way to handle this?